How to use the rewrite tactic in function arguments
I'd like to prove a simple mathematical theorem but I fail to get through the following subgoal:
IHn : divisible3 (n * n * n + n + n)
--------------------------------------(1/1)
divisible3 (S n * S n * S n + S n + S n)

It occured to me that replacing the S n terms by appropriate expressions containing only n might move the proof effort further. Replacing S n + S n by 2 + n + n by the tactics below Coq returns
Found no subterm matching "S n + S n" in the current goal.
assert (Rw1 : S n + S n = 2 + n + n ). ring. rewrite Rw1.
What would be the right way to accomplish tasks like this?
Addition:
The same technique to rewrite S n * S n * S n does work.

Bear in mind that + is left-associative. There is no S n + S n in (S n * S n * S n + S n) + S n.

This question comes from the way one reads an expression with several occurrences of the same binary operator.
   S n * S n * S n + S n + S n

Is an expression where two additions occur.  If the user is forced to use only binary operators for addition and parentheses, they can write different formulas.
  (S n * S n * S n + n) + n

or
  S n * S n * S n + (n + n)

These two expressions have the same mathematical meaning (in a human's eyes) but different structure.  In the first one, the express n + n does not occur.
Unfortunately, the display engine use an associativity rule, so that one of the two variants is displayed (and parsed) without parentheses, and the one that has no parenthesis is the first one.  In other words, when one types a + b + c without parentheses, it actually means (a + b) + c and the parentheses are silently removed.
If you load the Arith library, you can find a theorem that helps you re-write one form of the formula into the other.
Search (_ + _ + _).

There are several answers to this query, but the one that is relevant is Nat.add_assoc.
So if you add the following line before the one you propose:
rewrite <- Nat.add_assoc.

Your command should then be accepted.
